# Where are the VS Code Dev Container build logs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I'm getting an immediate build failure trying to build a dev container on a remote ssh host.
I had this working fine until i moved to a new server.  Below is the message I get when VS Code detects my .devcontainer files, prompts me to rebuild and I accept.  All it shows is this dialog - Where would be the log file for me to investigate further?

[image: ![enter image description here]

I've basically now stripped the project down to just the .devcontainer folder and further made it all very simple to try and debug what's happening here.  here are my .devcontainer files

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM alpine 
RUN echo "test test"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: test_container
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile

    command: sleep infinity
```

**devcontainer.json**

```
{
    "name": "test_container",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",  
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    "customizations": { 
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": ["ms-python.python"]
        }
    }
}
```

so now when i open vscode, it detects the devcontainer files and prompts to rebuild/open, but as soon as i do so, i get that useless dialogue popup.
further more, if try a new devcontainer from 'Dev Container: Try A Devcontainer Sample..', that works - so i dont think it is an ssh/remote issue.
puzzling

Comment: You can find the logs using the command Dev Container Developer: Show All Logs in the Command Palette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following commands in the command palette:

- Dev Containers Developer: Show All Logs...
- Dev Containers: Show Container Log
- Dev Containers: Show Previous Log